# Can java.util.Date store fraction of second when taken from an Oracle TIMESTAMP field?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

The code I am looking at fetches a database row as a Hibernate entity object.  One of the fields is a TIMESTAMP(6) in Oracle database.

From the code it looks like it is returned as java.util.Date.  When I print the variable I see the following:

```
DATE: >>>>>>>>>> 2022-08-04 10:27:02.947073
```

Can anyone explain what is the fraction after the seconds field?

Comment: When mentioning the data type of a column, mention the database engine as well. Data types and their names vary widely across databases.

Comment: The question had mentioned Oracle TIMESTAMP. Not sure more specific information was needed.

Comment: I hadn’t noticed the mention in the title. I’ll add a tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) within the second. So, it was 94.7% done with the second second in the 27th minute, etc. Yes, `j.u.Date` stores up to milliseconds. In fact, it's not a date at all, it stores an instant in time (which cannot be turned into a date unless we know exactly in which timezone we are).

Comment: Six digits means microseconds which excludes `java.util.Date` as the type given its limit of milliseconds. I would guess the type was perhaps  a `java.sql.Timestamp`.